# Typescript typesafe Store in non React Component

Tags: typescript, redux

Im looking for a way to use the Redux-Store in an non-react component.

The problem is that store.getState() does not have a typing.

I tried to use my own store interface as type for the class.

Something like:

```
interface Service {
    store: MyStore
}

class LoginService implements Service {
    store = store.getState()
    let valueFromStore = store.getState().value
}
```

it works and compiles, but both, the linter and the typescript-compiler through an error.

how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the linter for this page.
But can I ask you why are you using the Redux store in a non-react component?

It's not very advisible to mix React components with other Frontend Views...

Comment: thanks for the advice. I have a dynamic backend-url. static components and other react-components need to access it. What would you suggest for that?

Comment: I would create a util function which access the backend and import it into your components. Maybe I did not understand your case properly... Can you tell me more about your stack and what the backend URL is (API, ...)?

Comment: i have a react native app. you can choose a server(address or ip) to login. The Backend is a simple JSON-API